# Connection loss detection with poll()

Tags: c, tcp, client-server, polling

I am making a client server application. Previously in the application if the client  went down the server would try to reconnect ( i.e. if `recv()` on the server side returns 0 value the server would go back to accept connection ). Now I want to modify the server by allowing it to connect to multiple clients. I thought of using `poll()` so server could check on each client for sometime. I wanted to know with `poll` how can I check if the connection to client is lost?

Answer (score 0):

When use multiplex io with `poll`, you can handle connection shutdown with following events:

- `POLLIN` when there is data to read, and when you does the `read` or `recv` function call, make sure you checked the return value, typically a return value of `0` indicates that the connection has been shutdown. This is the same as your previous single client version.
- `POLLRDHUP` which indicates the peer has closed the connection, or shut down writing half of connection.
- `POLLERR` for other errors.

When the three event are triggered, it means the client has closed the connection or there is errors on the socket, you typically close the sockets.